# Is it possible in Python to create an instance method that takes as an argument an instance variable like this: var.method()?

Tags: python, methods, sudoku

I've been struggling on this problem for quite a while:
I've started creating a code that solves a Sudoku, and I've managed to get most of it right until now. I created a class called "Sudoku", which it contains one instance variable: the grid of the Sudoku with all the inserted numbers.

I've also created some methods that allow me to access or modify parts of the Sudoku, and for the moment there are no problems. But now I have to introduce a new instance variable, the grid of the Sudoku with the annotations for the numbers. The problem comes with the methods that I wrote before.

The code was:

```
    def get_line(self, line):
    if 0 < line < 10:
        return self.sudoku[9*(line-1):9*line]
    return None
```

As you can see in the method I just wrote

```
self.sudoku
```

("sudoku" is the instance variable that contains the grid with the inserted numbers, and it's a list containing 81 elements, which are the numbers of the Sudoku inserted line by line) and I directly modified the sudoku variable. But now I cannot access the grid with the annotations with this same method, because it would return the line of the Sudoku.

I was wondering if I could do something like this

```
self.sudoku.get_line()
```

or

```
self.annotations.get_line()
```

where I use a method that takes as an argument the variable that i write before calling the method itself. Is it possible to write a method that acts like this?

I know that there are some other ways to go around this specific problem, but I wanted to find if something like this is possible in Python.

Thanks to everyone that will try to help me, I wasn't able to find the solution to this anywhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. if each square in the grid contains both a number and an annotation, then each square should be an instance of a class, eg:

```
class SudokuSquare():
    def __init__(self, number=None, annotation=None):
        super().__init__(self)
        self.number, self.annotation = number, annotation

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.number or '')
```

If you populate your list with instances of these classes, instead of plain integers, then when you fetch a row, you fetch everything at once.  No need to have two parallel grids.

And then my other suggestion would be to use a list of lists to represent your rows and columns, like so:

class Sodoku():

```
def __init__(self):
    self.rows = []
    for _ in range(9):
        self.rows.append([ SukokuSquare() for _ in range(9) ])

def get_line(self, num):
    if num < 1 or num > 9:
        return None

    return self.rows[num-1]
```

Instantiating class `Sudoku` will give you a Sudoku object containing a list of 9 rows, each containing a list of 9 `SudokuSquare`s, each with a place to store a `number` and an `annotation`.

Now, if I want to set the number at line 9, position 9 to the value of 6, I would do:

puzzle = Sudoku()
puzzle.get_line(9)[8].number = 6

But then, I'm still directly accessing the list containing the line (row), and maybe I don't want to do that.. Then maybe you want another class called SudukoRow, which has a `get_square` method...

I'll leave that part for you to try to figure out...

Comment: Before I got any answer I sat at my desk and tried to figure this problem out, and my solution was to create a subclass called Operation, wich basically did all the operations needed (like get_row) for a given sudoku grid. In my case I created an object that was the grid with the numbers and one wich was the grid with the annotations. I mean, it worked, I was happy with it, but after your answer I'll definetly rethink my approach to it. Mainly because I had two different lists, and as you suggested I can have only one containing both the numbers and the annotations. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want

```
self.foo.getline(fie)
self.bar.getline(fum)
```

to be equivalent to

```
self.getline(foo, fie)
self.getline(bar, fum)
```

(a bit like letting `getline` have to different "selves")?

This being Python, there is probably some horrible trick that can be used, but isn't the obvious solution to have foo and bar be instances of a separate class that implements getline(), that the Sudoku class can delegate to?